# Generate dynamic ERB templates?

Tags: ruby, erb

I am using ERB in order to generate HTML snippets. So I have an (html.erb) template that looks like this:

```
<html><head><title>Artsy</title></head>
  <body>
    <div id='name-container'>
      <%= @name %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And after a render, it ends up looking like this:

```
<html><head><title>Artsy</title></head>
  <body>
    <div id='name-container'>
      Johnny
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a couple of related questions:

Say that I want the user to be able to modify the ERB templates in a visual way, so that he for example, can move the container with `id = 'name-container'` into another part of the template. What should I look into in order to do this?

ERB is a template engine for Ruby, and I am using it because the values that I have are coming from a Ruby app. However, if I want to research on alternatives on how to do this (having a template and be able to pass the parameters that it is expecting, such as @name), what should I look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User editable erb templates are a bad idea because they are not at all sandboxed: a user could easily write erb with destructive side effects (either intentionally or not) or end up relying on aspects of your application you want to change.

Use a templating language designed for this purpose, such as [liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org)

Comment: Frederick Cheung, that is exactly the kind of answer that I was looking for. I failed to find what I should Google for: Would it be dynamic templating language? Notice that I can be language agnostic, it doesn't have to be Ruby.

Comment: Googling for templating languages would probably have done it - there's not so many that you couldn't sift through them

Answer (score 0):

Using the [dom](https://rubygems.org/gems/dom) gem that I have developed, you can create HTML strings directly from Ruby code. Using it, you can do things like:

```
require "dom"
["foo".dom(:span, class: "bold"), "bar"].dom(:div).dom(:body).dom(:html)
# => "<html><body><div><span class=\"bold\">foo</span>bar</div></body></html>"
```